# yii-node socket not working on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, yii, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I have configured yii-node socket in Yii 1.1 and everything works fine on localhost. No issues at all.
Now that I am trying to host my project on Google Compute Engine, I was having issues binding external IP to internal IP in order to start NodeJs server which was sending 404 on socket.io.js. I was able to fix it by removing the host from `server.listen` method so that it can bind to any IP address and socket.io js file is loaded to the client with it's public IP. I have created a reserved static IP for our instance and used the same IP in the below configuration.

Client handshake to server is not working since the uinque url which is generated is still pointing to localhost on GCP when website is loaded. I believe it should be server-ip instead of localhost.

My Node-Socket configuration is

```
'nodeSocket' => array( 
'class' => 'application.extensions.yii-node-socket.lib.php.NodeSocket',
'host' => 'xxx.211.xxx.99', // default is 127.0.0.1, can be ip or domain name, without http 
'allowedServerAddresses' => [ "127.0.0.1", "xxx.211.xxx.99", "::ffff:xxx.211.xxx.99" ], 
'origin' => '*:*', 
'port' => 3001 // default is 3001, should be integer )
```

Below is the log when I try to fire events from Yii

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info - handshake authorized nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - set heartbeat interval for client nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - client authorized for /server
debug - websocket writing 1::/server
info - transport end (undefined)
debug - set close timeout for client nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - cleared close timeout for client nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client nvQHUiA9E1dBBKmHv69k
debug - discarding transport
```

server.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cookie = require('cookie');
var serverConfiguration = require('./server.config.js');
var storeProvider = express.session.MemoryStore;
var sessionStorage = new storeProvider();

var componentManager = require('./components/component.manager.js');
componentManager.set('config', serverConfiguration);

var eventManager = require('./components/event.manager.js');
var socketPull = require('./components/socket.pull.js');
var db = require('./components/db.js');
db.init(serverConfiguration.dbOptions);

componentManager.set('db', db);
componentManager.set('sp', socketPull);
componentManager.set('io', io);
componentManager.set('eventManager', eventManager);
componentManager.set('sessionStorage', sessionStorage);

server.listen(serverConfiguration.port);
console.log('Listening ' + serverConfiguration.host + ':' + serverConfiguration.port);

//  accept all connections from local server
if (serverConfiguration.checkClientOrigin) {
    console.log('Set origin: ' + serverConfiguration.origin);
    io.set("origins", serverConfiguration.origin);
}

//  client
io.of('/client').authorization(function (handshakeData,accept) {

    if (!handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
        return accept('NO COOKIE TRANSMITTED', false);
    }

    handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

    var sid = handshakeData.cookie[serverConfiguration.sessionVarName];
    if (!sid) {
        return accept('Have no session id', false);
    }

    handshakeData.sid = sid;
    handshakeData.uid = null;

    //  create write method
    handshakeData.writeSession = function (fn) {
        sessionStorage.set(sid, handshakeData.session, function () {
            if (fn) {
                fn();
            }
        });
    };

    //  trying to get session
    sessionStorage.get(sid, function (err, session) {

        //  create session handler
        var createSession = function () {
            var sessionData = {
                sid : sid,
                cookie : handshakeData.cookie,
                user : {
                    role : 'guest',
                    id : null,
                    isAuthenticated : false
                }
            };

            //  store session in session storage
            sessionStorage.set(sid, sessionData, function () {

                //  authenticate and authorise client
                handshakeData.session = sessionData;
                accept(null, true);
            });
        };

        //  check on errors or empty session
        if (err || !session) {
            if (!session) {

                //  create new session
                createSession();
            } else {

                //  not authorise client if errors occurred
                accept('ERROR: ' + err, false);
            }
        } else {
            if (!session) {
                createSession();
            } else {

                //  authorize client
                handshakeData.session = session;
                handshakeData.uid = session.user.id;
                accept(null, true);
            }
        }
    });

}).on('connection', function (socket) {

    //  add socket to pull
    socketPull.add(socket);

    //  connect socket to him channels
    componentManager.get('channel').attachToChannels(socket);

    //  bind events to socket
    eventManager.client.bind(socket);
});

//  server
io.of('/server').authorization(function (data, accept) {
    if (data && data.address) {
        if (data.headers['cookie']) {
            data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            if (data.cookie.PHPSESSID) {
                data.sid = data.cookie.PHPSESSID;
                var found = false;
                for (var i in serverConfiguration.allowedServers) {
                    if (serverConfiguration.allowedServers[i] == data.address.address) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    var createSession = function () {
                        var sessionData = {
                            sid : data.cookie.PHPSESSID,
                            cookie : data.cookie,
                            user : {
                                role : 'guest',
                                id : null,
                                isAuthenticated : false
                            }
                        };

                        //  store session in session storage
                        sessionStorage.set(data.cookie.PHPSESSID, sessionData, function () {

                            //  authenticate and authorise client
                            data.session = sessionData;
                            accept(null, true);
                        });
                    };
                    data.writeSession = function (fn) {
                        sessionStorage.set(data.cookie.PHPSESSID, data.session, function () {
                            if (fn) {
                                fn();
                            }
                        });
                    };
                    sessionStorage.get(data.cookie.PHPSESSID, function (err, session) {
                        if (err || !session) {
                            if (!session) {
                                createSession();
                            } else {
                                accept('ERROR: ' + err, false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (!session) {
                                createSession();
                            } else {

                                //  authorize client
                                data.session = session;
                                data.uid = session.user.id;
                                accept(null, true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    accept('INVALID SERVER: server host ' + data.address.address + ' not allowed');
                }
            } else {
                accept('PHPSESSID is undefined', false);
            }

        } else {
            accept('No cookie', false);
        }
    } else {
        accept('NO ADDRESS TRANSMITTED.', false);
        return false;
    }
}).on('connection', function (socket) {

    //  bind events
    eventManager.server.bind(socket);
});

componentManager.initCompleted();
```

Comment: I think that your code would be helpful. Is socket.io serving on a different ip?

Comment: @ZoeCarver I have edited the post with server code

Comment: Thanks. I will look over the code in the morning :)

Comment: Sure.. Appreciate your effort. :)

Comment: I am not exactly sure. I have been looking through the docs, the only thing that I might change is allowing more clients on `allowedServerAddresses `. sorry :P

Comment: No worries. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it myself.. :) I missed to look in the cached assets which had old code pointing to localhost and when I cleared the cached from yii assets folder, it worked. 
Configuration required just one change to remove the binding of host from `server.listen` method which I had already mentioned in the question so that it can accept requests from any IP address on Google Compute Engine.